# pyopencl crashes randomly after enqueueing a kernel on device

Tags: python, parallel-processing, opencl, scheduler, pyopencl

I am trying to perform grayscale ( a random operation I arbitrarily choose ) to perform in a heterogenous manner. If I have 100 pictures, i want to split them across all the available devices in the computer so that they will finish at the same time thus producing a faster implementation compared to using a single device.

The kernel code I am trying to run is this:

```c
// GRAYSCALE = """
__kernel void grayscale(__global uchar *input,
                        __global uchar *output,
                        uint width,
                        ulong size,
                        const ulong chunk_size)
{
    ulong gid_column = get_global_id(0);
    ulong gid_row = get_global_id(1);
    ulong pixel;
    float luma,r,g,b;
    while(1){};
    for(ulong i = 0; i<chunk_size;i++){
        pixel = ((gid_column*chunk_size)+(gid_row*width)+i)*3;
        if(pixel<size-3){
            r = input[pixel+0];
            g = input[pixel+1];
            b = input[pixel+2];
            luma = 0.299f * b + 0.587f * g + 0.114f * r;
            output[pixel+0] = luma;
            output[pixel+1] = luma;
            output[pixel+2] = luma;
        }
        else break;
    } 
}
///    """
```

The `while(1){};` is added intentionally because I want to see how scheduler will work, and I need the device to spend more time on the task.

This is where the issue occurs:

```
    def grayscale(self, images):
        result = []
        device_queues = {}
        device_queues_status = {}
        DEBUG_PROCESED_TASKS = {}
        selected_device = None

        for device in self.opencl_devices:
            device_queues[device] = []
            device_queues_status[device] = 0
            DEBUG_PROCESED_TASKS[device.device_name] = 0

        for image in images:
            for device in device_queues:
                device_queues_status[
                    device] = OpenCLFunctions.Pictures.get_work_amount(
                        device_queues[device])
            selected_device = min(device_queues_status,
                                  key=device_queues_status.get)
            ev = selected_device._grayscale(image)
            device_queues[selected_device].append(ev)
            DEBUG_PROCESED_TASKS[selected_device.device_name] += 1
        print(DEBUG_PROCESED_TASKS)


    def _grayscale(self, input_image):
        ENQUEUE_PROCESS_ASYNC = opencl_device.enqueue_nd_range_kernel
        ENQUEUE_COPY_ASYNC = opencl_device.enqueue_copy
        OPENCL_BUFFER = opencl_device.Buffer

        program = self.kernels["_grayscale"].grayscale
        buffers = OpenCLBuffer(
            OPENCL_BUFFER(self.context,
                          opencl_device.mem_flags.READ_WRITE
                          | opencl_device.mem_flags.ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
                          size=input_image.size),
            OPENCL_BUFFER(self.context,
                          opencl_device.mem_flags.READ_WRITE
                          | opencl_device.mem_flags.ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
                          size=input_image.size))
        input_copy = ENQUEUE_COPY_ASYNC(self.queue,
                                        buffers.opencl_buffer_input,
                                        input_image,
                                        is_blocking=False)
        program.set_args(
            buffers.opencl_buffer_input, buffers.opencl_buffer_output,
            opencl_device_numpy.uint32(input_image.shape[0]),
            opencl_device_numpy.uint64(buffers.size),
            opencl_device_numpy.uint64(self.CHUNK_PROCESSING_SIZE))
        max_work_group_size_kernel = program.get_work_group_info(
            opencl_device.kernel_work_group_info.WORK_GROUP_SIZE, self.device)
        prefered_local_size = program.get_work_group_info(
            opencl_device.kernel_work_group_info.
            PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE, self.device)
        global_size = OpenCLFunctions.Pictures._get_global_size_picture(
            input_image.shape[0], input_image.shape[1],
            self.CHUNK_PROCESSING_SIZE)
        local_size, global_size = OpenCLFunctions.OpenCLScheduler._get_optimal_local_global_size(
            global_size, max_work_group_size_kernel,
            self.device.max_work_group_size, self.device.max_work_item_sizes,
            prefered_local_size)
        try:
            ev = ENQUEUE_PROCESS_ASYNC(self.queue,
                                       program,
                                       global_size,
                                       local_size,
                                       wait_for=[input_copy])
            return [ev, buffers.opencl_buffer_output]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Basically, this function will assign something to process to the first device. The next round it comes, it will assign a new task to the least busy device. The problem it is after the function being called here `ev = selected_device._grayscale(image)` the debugger is no longer able to view the variables, and the main thread from python hangs. it does work a bit after enqueueing the kernel, but it acts sporadically.

Is there something that maybe I am forgetting?

P.S: This is just for research and experimenting, I just want to understand this particular issue.

Tried:

- prevent the python garbage collector from collecting the events
- use a long for loop instead of a `while(1){};`
- add to watch the variables I am following so that I can catch the event being busy after it gets to scheduler.
- using smaller data

expectation:
What I am expecting is to see a task being busy (because of

```
while(1){};
```

on the GPU, the scheduler sees it is busy, then it assigns the next task to other device (CPU or iGPU)

Comment: that `while(1){};`  will block forever... the driver will probably kill the kernel *eventually*, which may look like a crash.

Comment: Basically like a watchdog, right? if yes, can it be disabled just for debugging purposes?

Comment: @Seeven some drivers might allow you to control behavior like that for debugging, but even if you did, it would still probably keep your GPU locked up and unable to render anything in the meantime - effectively freezing your system.